# Packaging new ASP.NET 5 applications

Tags: .net, deployment, web-deployment, webdeploy, asp.net-core

When it's released will I still be able to create WebDeploy-compatible packages? Currently I do it like

```
msbuild my.csproj /t:Package
```

If there is an equivalent how will it look like? Can I deploy the package to non-IIS hosts?

**Update:** (thanks to @Victor Hurdugaci !)

`kpm` becomes available after installing `kvm` and then doing `kvm upgrade`. Then, `kpm bundle` fails:

> 'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. The 'prepare' script failed with status code 1.

OK, it's broken for the moment but what are the promises? Will we get cross platform packages? WebDeploy compatibility? Cannot google anything.

Comment: did u try kpm pack ?

Comment: It says "Unknown command" (kvm build 10319)

Comment: see the doc about kpm on the [aspnet/Home wiki](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Package-Manager)

Comment: according to this [blog post about VS 2015 CT6](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/23/aspnet-5-updates-for-feb-2015.aspx), the pack command is now the bundle command

Answer (score 1):

The command that will create a deployable bundle is:

```
kpm bundle --runtime <name of runtime>
```

Example:

```
kpm bundle --runtime kre-coreclr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta3
```

The runtime is optional. Don't specify it if the environment where you deploy already has the K Runtime.

If you have the latest VS 2015 (CTP6), kpm should be available on the `PATH`. If not, follow the instruction on the [Home repo](https://github.com/aspnet/home/)

Answer (score 0):

To address the "'grunt' is not recognized" error, run the following on the command prompt:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```